# Serving GitHub Pages site with custom domain name via Cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, https, domain-name, cloudflare, github

http://appleseedhq.net/ is a GitHub Pages site hosted at https://appleseedhq.github.io/.

I'm following Cloudflare's tutorial to enable HTTPS at https://appleseedhq.net/:

https://blog.cloudflare.com/secure-and-fast-github-pages-with-cloudflare/

I've followed and double-checked all the steps scrupulously but at the moment the site appears to use an invalid certificate and browsers such as Firefox issue a warning:

[image: Firefox's Invalid Certificate Warning]

Here is our Cloudflare setup:

- Crypto:

[image: SSL setup on Cloudflare]

- DNS:

[image: DNS setup on Cloudflare]

- Name servers:

[image: Name servers setup on Cloudflare]

At this point I'm out of ideas. Could it be simply that settings need to propagate? In my past experience, I've never had to wait longer than a few minutes at most. In this case a couple hours have elapsed already. I suspect that I'm making a simple mistake.

EDIT: It appears to be working correctly for some other people. Could it be some caching on my side? I've tried flushing Windows' and my browser's DNS caches but to no effect.

Comment: Github Pages supports HTTPS / SSL for custom domains since 2018... https://github.blog/2018-05-01-github-pages-custom-domains-https/ .

Answer (score 0):

The configuration was correct. It simply took forever for settings to propagate. I'm leaving the question as (yet another) example of how to configure HTTPS for a GitHub Pages site with a custom domain name.

Comment: Github Pages supports HTTPS / SSL for custom domains since 2018... https://github.blog/2018-05-01-github-pages-custom-domains-https/ .